# Disable thread leak test in ThreadSanitizer?

Tags: catch2, thread-sanitizer

I'm using ThreadSanitizer with Catch2. Unfortunately, ThreadSanitizer is finding thread leaks with Catch2 and Thread race conditions in my code. Is there any way to disable ThreadSanitizer's thread leak detection but leaving on its race condition testing?

Comment: Are your threads detached? I find that it reports detached threads as leaked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the right thing to do was to fix the bug. I was creating threads and not joining them or deleting the `std::thread` object.